# ¿Qué pasa si llamo a la función main() en un programa hecho en C++?

Tags: c++, funciones

Tengo este código:

```
int max1(int a, int b){
    int m = a;
    
    if(b > m){
        m = b;
    }
    return m;
}


int main(){
    cout<<max1(5,6)<<endl;
    cout<<main()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

He querido probar ese código, pero tengo miedo a que se dañe mi computadora. ¿Qué pasa si se llama a la función main()?

Comment: El mundo está hecho para los valientes. Ejecuta! ;-)

Comment: El tema se llama "recursividad", investiga.

Comment: Ya sé que es la recursividad y la he investigado, pero todavía no la domino al 100%, pero me falta un poco más y ya la podré entender.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cabe la posibilidad de que semejante código no compile, pues llamar explícitamente a la función `main` está explícitamente prohibido en [el estándar de C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) (traducción mía):

> 6.6.1 La función `main`
>
> ---
>
> 3. **La función `main` no debe ser usada dentro del programa**.

Dado que el estándar prohíbe explícitamente llamar a `main`, los compiladores posiblemente se nieguen a compilar dicho código, si algún compilador compila dicho código muy posiblemente muestre una alarma y si se ejecuta dicho código dará lugar a un [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido).

Comment: Ya entiendo. Preguntaba porque compilé en Dev-C++ y extrañamente no me dió ningún error.

Answer (score 0):

Tu programa va a compilar y va a correr. No va a dañar tu computadora, aunque si va a fallar probablemente con un *stack overflow*.

Si en tu programa main hicieras que, ante alguna condición, no se llamara a la función main y se saliera de la misma, el programa finalizaría sin problemas.

Para correrlo solo le agregué un par de líneas al principio del código

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

y compila tal y como está. La ejecución arroja un `segmentation fault` a los pocos segundos de ejecutar en Ubuntu 22.04, que es lo que tenía a mano para ejecutarlo.

No deberías tener miedo de ejecutar tu código, hay muy pocas posibilidades de que puedas hacer algo malo a tu computadora haciéndolo, y seguramente aprenderás bastante.